# Reset padding on <select>

Tags: html, css

I need to set padding on `<select>` to the same value as the `<input type="text" />`, so the text in both fields will be aligned to the same vertical line. For testing purposes I've set `margin` and `padding` to 0 on both fields, but the text is still indented in the `select` element. I've also tried changing `text-indent`, but with no effect. What am I missing?

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjahjh2n/)

Comment: You can always add an additional left padding just on the input?

Comment: you can give an other calss to select and give a -ive left margin to this new class

Comment: These are hacks, not reliable solutions.

Comment: To get a non-hacky, *cross browser*, and, hell, even cross Operating System solution, you will have to go down the jQuery / javascript road and replace the `<select>` completely. Default browser inputs are a pain to style.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `text-indent` to your input fields.

CSS:

```
input.edit{ text-indent:4px; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/cjahjh2n/1/)

Comment: I want to reset padding in the select element, not change it in the text field. Also a hardcoded '4px' isn't a reliable cross-browser solution.

Comment: I don't see any other solution to your problem. Another option is to use a custom select box using jquery. Just for your reference see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10001291/3008050